# Innosetup passing in var from [setup] to procedure in [code]

Tags: inno-setup

I have something like:

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode = {#MyArchInstallIn64BitMode}

[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Value: String;
  I: Integer;
  LogList: TStringList;
begin
if (ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode = 'x64') then begin
//code
end else begin
//else code
end;
```

Where ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode is an include. How can I pass ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode into my procedure? And i want it to be declared as a string so i can perform string operations on it

Comment: Are you asking how to determine in a script if you're doing a 32 or 64 bit install?

Comment: If you are just looking for architecture you can use this in your code: `ProcessorArchitecture`.
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_processorarchitecture

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you've posted in your question, you *could* do this like so:

```
if '{#MyArchInstallIn64BitMode}' = 'x64' then begin
```

Or, given that this is fixed at compile time anyway, you can use ISPP conditionals:

```
#if MyArchInstallIn64BitMode == "x64"
   ...
#endif
```

**HOWEVER** this sort of code really doesn't make much sense to begin with -- all it does is to let you *at compile time* make separate 32-bit and 64-bit installers, completely irrespective of what the user actually has.

Have a look at the 64BitTwoArch.iss example script included with Inno, which demonstrates how to make a single installer that will work for both 32-bit and 64-bit installs, which is the preferred method.

Even that is only useful if you actually have both a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of your application; if your application is 32-bit only (which is the most common case) then you typically don't need to do anything at all -- the default behaviour of Inno will correctly install it on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.